# Enable Horiziontal Scrolling with SHIFT Scroll

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, scrollview

###### TLDR:

I'm looking for an implementation of the ScrollView which does the horizontal scroll with *SHIFT + Mouse_Scroll*.

Alternatively any implementation of the ScrollView widget which bind the `on_scroll_start`, `on_scroll_stop`, `on_scroll_move` callbacks to the `on_mouse_down`, `on_mouse_up` events of the `Window` class. I need the `modifiers` argument passed by the callback to implement the horizontal scroll.

###### Sample code:

```
__version__ = '1.0.1'

from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<ScrolllabelLabel>:
    do_scroll_x: True
    do_scroll_y: True
    always_overscroll: False
    effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
    Label:
        text: root.text
        font_size: 18
        # text_size: None, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        size_hint_x: None
        width: self.texture_size[0]
''')


class ScrolllabelLabel(ScrollView):
    text = StringProperty('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n' * 100)


runTouchApp(ScrolllabelLabel())
```

Vertical Scrolling with the mouse wheel is no problem. This works. However, I would like to achieve horizontal scrolling with the keyboard shortcut *SHIFT + Mouse_Scroll*.

Now I found, that I could bind a function to on_mouse_down in the [Window Class](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html) and it would provide me with the both the button (scrollup, scrolldown) as well as all triggered modifiers ('ctrl', 'numlock').

Now I would like my implementation to be identical to kivy.
So that it also has a smooth after scroll, respects the always_overscroll, do_scroll, ... attributes of the ScrollView. However I have not found a function in the ScrollView API which implements this.

Furthermore I looked at the source code of the ScrollView. I was not too thorough, I just used the debugger of PyCharm. Doing so, I found that the `touch object` given to the `on_scroll_start` method didn't have the modifiers that the `on_mouse_down` to the Window had. I also sanity checked that in the docs of the `MotionEvent`, no modifiers property.

Now this hinders me from simply extending the Class and implementing my own scroll method which reads the modifiers and triggers then a horizontal scroll accordingly.

While analyzing the source code I also found that kivy was looking for 'scrollleft' and 'scrollright' as well but apparently using *SHIFT + Mouse_Scroll* In Linux doesn't issue a left or right scroll event.

Upon finding this, I tried a mouse which has the ability to horizontally scroll. With this mouse I was able to achieve horizontal scrolling however the animation was not smoothed as with the vertical scrolling. For every click issued, it would move a fixed amount instead of the speed animation which the vertical scroll has.

Now my main priority is to get the scrolling with *SHIFT + Mouse_Scroll* working.
Secondly I would like to implement the same effects as the vertical scroll (I'm a perfectionist.)

...

Ok, I just looked through the call stack and realized that there's no chance of getting this done without rewriting the methods. `on_touch_down` is issued by the Window class, so the modifiers attributes are not stripped away somewhere in between where I could have recovered them. I (would) have to implement my own scroll methods.

If you know of an existing implementation of this functionality could you provide me with the source?

Thanks for your help.

A.S.

Comment: I've created a [Fork of the kivy project](https://github.com/AliSot2000/kivy) which now implements the horizontal scroll wheel emulation with the shift key. The fork is pending a pull into the main kivy repo.

Comment: In addition, it was suggested to me, to use the [gestures4kivy](https://github.com/Android-for-Python/gestures4kivy) package. However I found that what I came up with to have horizontal scrolling, was not working with nested ScrollViews. Since I didn't get any further comment on how to solve my issue with this package, I didn't pursue  it further.